# Change style of a EnhancedGrid line on "onRowClick" event

Tags: dojox.grid

I want to change a color of grid line but without selecting it. It means I cannot use onStyleRow event as it reacts only for 'selected', 'odd' or 'over' event.

Any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I found an updateRowStyles(idxRow) function, but no idea how to use it (how to pass syles etc.) and not sure if it will solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You cant change your style this way:

```
var layout = [
{ field: 'denumire', name: 'Denumire', width: '200px', height: '25px', styles: "color:red;" },
{ field: 'valoare', name: 'Valoare', width: '252px', styles: "color:red;"}];
```

or use formatter in layout grid

```
var layout = [
{ field: 'denumire', name: 'Denumire', width: '200px', height: '25px',  formatter:  function (value, rowIndex) {
       return "<div style='height:110px;text-overflow:ellipsis;color:red;'>"+value+"</div>"
} },
{ field: 'valoare', name: 'Valoare', width: '252px',
formatter: function (value, rowIndex) {
       return "<div style='height:110px;text-overflow:ellipsis;color:red;'>"+value+"</div>"
}}];
```